# Why is "ENV variable 'S3_KEY' needs to be set" being thrown on deployment?

Tags: deployment, amazon-s3, heroku, heroku-san

I'd like to use [`heroku_san`](https://github.com/fastestforward/heroku_san) to deploy multiple environments to [heroku](http://www.heroku.com). I'm using dragonfly for image handling and S3 for storage. Usually you can add your key and secret for the storage using `heroku config:add S3_KEY=… S3_SECRET=…` directly.

So I've added these details to the `heroku.yml` file used by `heroku_san`:

```
staging:
  app: app-staging
  config: &default
    BUNDLE_WITHOUT: "development:test"
    S3_KEY: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
    S3_SECRET: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    S3_BUCKET: app-staging
```

but when deploying I'm still getting:

```
rake aborted!
ENV variable 'S3_KEY' needs to be set - use
    heroku config:add S3_KEY=XXXXXXXXX
```

What am I missing here? Is there a better way then storing this information in a YML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution/work-around:

```
heroku config:add S3_KEY=XXX S3_SECRET=XXX --app app-staging
```

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to run `heroku config:add` manually. Just run heroku_san's config task:

```
$ rake all heroku:config
```

Repeat this whenever you update the heroku.yml file.

I was confused about this too, since it's strangely absent from heroku_san's documentation, but the option does appear in the list of rake tasks:

```
$ rake -T
```

and in the heroku_san code: https://github.com/fastestforward/heroku_san/blob/master/lib/heroku_san/tasks.rb

Comment: I forked heroku_san to update the documentation, and my changes were just merged in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run the command `rake all heroku:rack_env`.  This command will then set the environment configurations for you based on your heroku_san YAML configuration.

Comment: Looks promising. Gotta give that a try. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks.  Will you let me know if it works/didn't work for you?  Cheers!

Comment: Sure thing. Might take a bit, though.

Comment: heroku:rack_env only sets the RACK_ENV environment variable.

Comment: @jhiro009 According to their [documentation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#rack_env_and_rails_env), "... On the Aspen and Bamboo stacks, RAILS_ENV will automatically mirror whatever is in RACK_ENV."

Comment: True: if you only need to set RAILS_ENV, and you're using the right stack, heroku:rack_env will get the job done. But my point was that it won't set everything in heroku.yml. I'd rather keep my configuration data in one file, only need one command (heroku:config), and not have to change my approach for a new stack (i.e. cedar).